# Page Table Management

Tags: operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

I understood the concept of paging in OS , just wanted to know where the page table is present. Is it present on the Main -Memory or in secondary memory .Expecting a reply on the same .

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some 2nd level page tables can be swapped out to the disk just like any other pages, if the CPU/OS design allows.

You don't want to swap out the first level page table and certain pages and page tables of the kernel itself, though. If you do, you may dead-lock the system.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response , i have searched completely across the internet to know where the page table is placed i haven't got any answer for the same . so as per your answer i beleive that it is mainly placed in main memory